# Meteor js and multiplayer games

Tags: javascript, meteor, multiplayer

I started to learn Meteor and I realized that it could probably be good solution for simple multiplayer game because of its reactivity. Is real time exchange between client-minimongo-database-client fast enough for exchanging player coordinates? Or it is bad solution and I should do it without database in the middle, just with direct web sockets connection? Multiplayer concept is new to me, so maybe I'm wrong all the way.

Comment: can you change your title to more meaning question like "Is Meteor suitable for Multiplayer games?"

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is by far the best of the best technology available among the other realtime technologies. Meteor is so efficiently fast both in terms of memory management and request handling. I have already deployed a Meteor on a CENTOS Linux distribution VPS server (Ideally you must choose DebianOS for its ease of deployment with just one command "mup").

Meteor is full stack ready packaged material where you just need to have JavaScript knowledge and Meteor know how. Below are some other realtime technologies available in market like,

1. **PHP(Laravel/ Yii2) + REDIS + SOCKET.IO** OR
2. **JAVA(Play Framework) + HAZELCAST + SOCKET.IO** OR
3. **REACT + FLUX** OR
4. **REACT + REDUX**, **Polymer** etc.

You will have to learn every framework and study the performance benchmarking on your system, whereas in Meteor, you just need to kick start with framework. Meteor learning curves is almost flat, if you are ok with javascript, you can definitely go for Meteor JS.

To start learning via videos , below are the links

1. [Intermediate LevelUp tuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI8IslJHSag&list=PLLnpHn493BHFYZUSK62aVycgcAouqBt7V)
2. [Basic Walkthrough for Meteor 1.4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFNX6riJtcc&list=PLLnpHn493BHGaNQgSl1lppoNrpjlr24z5)

You can easily install Meteor on your machine. then just run command below at you desired directory level;

> **meteor create --full your-project-name**

With above project you wil understand the basic flow of latest architecture and folder structure of Meteor 1.4.4.2 latest.

> **NOTE** : Meteor is heavily funded as I know and has drasctically grown with its
>   community support. I have worked on all above mentioned technologies,
>   Meteor reduces your project development efforts by more than half of
>   time and man power. You can develop a Huge website alone with Meteor
>   without needing man power for it.