# Real time Web application + Mobile Application which Node framework should i prefer

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, sails.js

I am totally a newbie in the Server side Javascript platform, i have only background in PHP Framwworks. Currently  I am starting a realtime web application which include live updates,push notification,sheduling etc..
i want to develop a web application and a mobile application.
which framwork should i learn.
i heared about Sails.JS for realtime Applicaiton. if i use sails which front end should i use, react or angular js, what about meteor? i am confused.
which framework is comparitivily easy to get started

Comment: Recommendations are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You'll probably have better luck at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have already answered similar kind of question couple of days back, you must read this, you'll be much happy reading this. go for `METEOR JS`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003284/meteor-js-and-multiplayer-games/44003903#44003903

Comment: I'm close to deploy an app using `MeteorJS + VueJS`. I work for few months using this set of tools. I'm in love with Vue. It's easy to learn and robust frontend framework. I've used Angular, React and Blaze(MeteorJS default frontend). Vue was the most enjoyable so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build real time applications using nodejs from scratch. However, you are better off using meteorjs as it comes bundled with lot of libraries baked in. The important ones are related to websockets which allow 2 way near real time communications using their ddp protocol.

Meteor gives you a web app output, which can be manually be converted to a Cordova/Phone gap application. However, meteor comes with cli for automating that as well.

Meteor-angular is quite robust and mature now interms of giving you full stack reactivity. as in updates on mongodb are pushed to browser using Meteor's subscribe. And any changes in browser (mini mongo) is observed and updated in UI using Angular.

React - no idea. Try out the examples over the net.

Meteor though locks into MongoDB only. So if you are concerned with any RDBMS, have a second thought